# How to toggle between last row and all rows in a table using React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, state

Hey you may not be able to run it, but I was wondering how can I use the ChevronDownIcon to toggle between all rows to display only one row which should be the last item of the object array an example of the array I have to map through is as follows:

```
[
{ id: 1,
  dummy: value, 
  dummy2: value2,
  "itemData": [
{
  id: 100,
  tableData1: value
  tableData2: value
},
{
  id: 200,
  tableData1: value
  tableData2: value
},
]
{ id: 2,
  dummy: value, 
  dummy2: value2,
  "itemData": [
{
  id: 300,
  tableData1: value
  tableData2: value
},
{
  id: 400,
  tableData1: value
  tableData2: value
}
]
}
]
```

it looks something along those lines. Is it possible to do it in the one component? do i need to make a separate component that maps through the array to only show the last row and render between the two? Please advise or point me in the right direction.

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: Sorry about the styling, i forgot to prettify my code.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It's not copyable, and it's not searchable. It's also harder to read.

Comment: Use something like https://stackblitz.com/ to showcase what you have - it'll make it easier to provide a solution

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up. but the app is huge so its to much code. thats just one component